# SetState update values on state and Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

The problem is that calling unCheckAllColums updates the data of the set state (configEdit, configNoEdit) and additionally updates the value that comes from the props, and it should only update the configEdit

```
export fuction HookConfigsUser(configUser){

    const initValues = { 
        configEdit: configUser; // this value only edit 
        configNoEdit: configUser; // this value use to recover info 
    }
    
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initValues)

    const unCheckAllColums = () => { 

        let editValue = { ...configEdit,}
        let setListEdit = editValue.config.map((conf) => {
          if (conf.enableEditShow === false) {
            conf.show = true
          } else {
            conf.show = false
          }
          return conf
        })
    
        editValue.config = setListEdit
        editValue.isEdit = true

        const toSetAllstate = {
          ...values,
          configEdit: editValue,
        }
        setValues(toSetAlstate)
    }

    const recoverInfo(){ 
        setValues({ 
            ...values, 
            configEdit: values.configNoEdit,
    }) }

    return [unCheckAllColums, recoverInfo] 
}
```

When calling the function all the variables are updated, those that are in setstate and the props and only the value inside state called configEdit should be updated.

Comment: post is update with setstate fuction, thanks